# Equivalent product option code in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

**Magento 2.3.3**

I tried rewriting the code I have for Magento 1, but i cant manage. The code can be found on https://pastebin.com/8rKJh0j7. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: link is not working.

Comment: It is, I just tried ... here it comes again: https://pastebin.com/8rKJh0j7